# 'calendar_for' in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby

Hi so im trying to display a calendar which has a number of film titles inside, the problem is that im want to pull the date from another model and its not working.

**current code in the view file(film)**

```
<%= calendar_for @films, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month do |calendar| %>
<%= calendar.head('Sun','Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat') %>
<%= calendar.day(:day_method => :date_of_release) do |date, films| %>
<%= date.day %>
<ul>
<% for film in films %>
  <%= link_to h(film.title), film %>
  </br>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

that code seems to work just fine and displays the films according to their date of release which is a attribute of the film model what i want to do is to display the date it screens on i.e. to pull the date from the 'showing' model. So far i got..

```
<%= calendar_for @film.showings, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month do |calendar|%>
<%= calendar.head('Sun','Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat') %>
<%= calendar.day(:day_method => :date) do |date, films| %>
<%= date.day %>
<ul>
  <% for showing in showings %>
  <%= link_to h(showing.film.title), film %>
  </br>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

but keep getting the error "undefined method `showings' for nil:NilClass"

the two models are related...film- has_many :showings & showing- belongs_to :film

code in the film controller:

def whats_on
@films = Film.all
@date = params[:month] ? Date.strptime(params[:month]) : Date.today
end

Comment: can you show us your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables `@films` and `@date` are defined in controller. So you can use them in html template. But `@film` is not defined. By default it has `nil` value. You should initialize it

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<% for showing in @film.showings %>
```